# Scroll up event for chrome not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

So I have a simple layout of,

```
<a name="#A1"></a>
<div></div>
<a name="#A2"></a>
<div></div>
<a name="#A3"></a>
<div></div>
```

And Im using the script below to jump to the next anchor point on mouse scroll event. I have tested it and it works on Firefox and IE but on Chrome only scrolling down works, when you scroll up nothing happens.

```
(function() {
  var delay = false;

  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
    });
  });
})();
```

The error that im getting is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: So for anyone else with this problem I learned that "getElementsByTagName" is blocked by chrome so instead I gave all the divs a class and used "getElementsByClassName" instead and everything is now working smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "getElementsByTagName" to "getElementsByClassName"
    (function() {
     var delay = false;

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if(delay) return;

delay = true;
setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("full-height");
if(wd < 0) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t >= 40) break;
  }
}
else {
  for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t < -20) break;
  }
}
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
});
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-getclientrects)

> If the element on which it was invoked does not have an associated
>   layout box return an empty sequence and stop this algorithm.

`getClientRects()` function may return empty list.  So element at `[0]` index may not exist (undefined). Thus you should check length of the list before accessing element in it.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't look right if you're trying to get the computed `top` of an element.

```
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
```

This should use `offsetTop`.

```
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].offsetTop;
```

Comment: getClientRects() returns rectangles, not DOM elements.